# NetApp Performance Archiver failed to close file

Tags: netapp

I have a newly configured (not by me) NetApp FAS-2040 running OnTAP 8.0.2.  It's spewing a log message every 15 seconds:

```
[perf.archive.file.close.fail:warning]: Performance archiver failed to close file: /etc/log/stats/archive/stats_archive_data_{numbers}.gz. (11079)
```

My Googlefu is not strong enough to find a relevant answer to how to fix the issue, or even how to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

That was a early release and probably has hundreds of weird little bugs. You should plan an update, and if it doesn't go away, come back.